# pandas fails while passing conditional selection

Tags: python, pandas

While working with pandas Dataframe object and using the conditional selection from the DataFrame it gives an error as follows, while i see while looking through some of the videos where same works on Jupiter notebook.

However, it clearly states the error below but i did not found a way around to fix it even though i searched upon on various SO post but did not get identical error solution

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Below is the code content which i'm using with puthon3.6.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df  = pd.DataFrame({'coln1': ['1', '2', '3'],
                    'coln2': ['111', '222', '111'],
                    'coln3': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']})

print(df[df['coln1']>2])
```

Any help or direction are much appreciated, while i'm still looking around myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert column to numeric by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print(df[df['coln1'].astype(int)>2])
```

More general solution if some non numeric values, which are converted to `NaN`s by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and parameter `errors='coerce'`:

```
print(df[pd.to_numeric(df['coln1'], errors='coerce')>2])
```